# Запуск приложения WinForm с параметрами из cmd

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

Всем привет как узнать что приложение было запущено с определенным параметром из cmd?   
Есть определенный параметр "Show Version" и при запуске 
 cmd > test.exe Show Version  
приложение должно выкинуть окно с номером версии и закрыться.  
 Вопрос как мне узнать в приложении что был вызов с параметром? и параметр тот что мне нужен  
Я нашел в свойства-> отладка -> Аргументы командной строки  
 но даже если я там впишу аргумент что сделать в коде 
нужно что то типа:  
 
If (был запуск с аргументом &&  аргумент == ...)  
Приложение WinForm на C#  
Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создайте проект winforms и найдите файл `Program.cs` В нем находится точка входа в приложение. Функция Main принимает параметры `string[] args`, с которыми вы запускаете приложение

UDP

от @Alexander Petrov добавление:

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: Все гениальное просто!! Спасибо я чего только не нарыл в интернете)

Comment: Также эти параметры можно получить из `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`.

Comment: @Bulat - галочка слева - щёлк :)